# Why this Statement Show Index Scan in Exec Plan?

Tags: sql, database-administration, query-performance, database-tuning

I have two statements that return the same result, but produce different execution plans.

- First  >>> Index Seek
- Second >>> Index Scan

Can anyone explain why?

### Example

```
CREATE TABLE OrderDetails (intOrderId int, intItemId int, dtOrderDate Datetime, intQty int, intPrice int, intDiscount int)
GO

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_OrderId ON OrderDetails(intOrderId)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCI_ItemId ON OrderDetails(intItemId)
GO

-- Populate Data
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @i int
SET @i =10
WHILE @i < 100000
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO OrderDetails
     VALUES (@i, round(rand()*9999,0)+1, getdate() - round(rand()*999,0), round(rand()*99,0)+1, round(rand()*9999,0)+1, round(rand()*99,0)+1)

     SET @i = @i + 1
END
GO

-- Check Execution Plans

-- NCI SEEK
SELECT intOrderId, intItemId 
FROM   OrderDetails
WHERE  intItemId = 600 * 10

-- NCI SCAN
SELECT intOrderId, intItemId 
FROM   OrderDetails
WHERE  intItemId/10 = 600
```

Comment: Can you try to rephrase the issue?  I really don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: @Mostafa - I reworded the initial sentence to clarify your question. If that is not what you intended, please feel free to [edit].

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons...

1. Because SQL Server doesn't algebraically manipulate your WHERE clause.
2. Because there are 10 values that match your second query

What I mean by the first comment is that the optimiser can see that you're doing something to the `intItemId`, but it doesn't try to find a short-cut.  Instead it has to perform the `/10` on every row to see what the result is.

*(It doesn't know that 6000/10 = 600 but that 5999 doesn't.  So it tries it on every row.)*

That links in to the second reason.  Your question implies that you expect only row `intItemId = 6000` to be returned by your second query. But `6001/10` through to `6009/10` all equal `600` too, due to integer arithmetic.  So, the algebraic manipulation of `x/10=y` becoming `x=y*10` isn't valid when you do integer arithmetic.  Which is part of the reason the optimiser doesn't try.

In short: Whenever you manipulate the indexed field in virtually ***any*** way, you'll prevent the use of the index and get a scan rather than a seek.

Comment: The true algebraic manipulation of `inItemId / 10 = 600` is `intItemId BETWEEN 600*10 AND 600*10+10-1`, something the optimiser won't do for you.  *You* are expected to re-arrange conditions like that to ensure that the indexed field doesn't have to be manipulated.